# Редирект переменных в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, поиск, http-status-code-301

Добрый день проблема с редиректом. Раньше поисковый запрос на сайте выглядел вот так:

```
http://сайт/search.php?search=запрос
```

После редизайна стал выглядеть так:

```
http://сайт/search?s=запрос
```

Суть проблемы: Нужно перенаправить трафик с старых страниц на новые.

В .htaccess прописал вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)search\=(.*)

RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /search?s=%{QUERY_STRING}$1 [L,R=301]
```

Работает не совсем корректно, в строку поиска передает search=запрос добавляя при этом лишний search=

Если прописать вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)search\=(.*)

RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /search?s=$1 [L,R=301]
```

В таком случае редиректит на пустую страницу поиска.

Как настроить правильно? Как передать только саму переменную =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте %2 вместо $1

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)search=(.*)$

RewriteRule ^search\.php$ /search?s=%2 [L,R=301]
```

Если тестируете в Chrome, учтите, что браузер кэширует 301 редирект. Нужно тестировать с открытым DevTools и включенной опцией Disable cache (while DevTools is open). Либо для тестов использовать 302 редирект вместо 301.

Comment: Спасибо помогло =)